# Alphabetically sort array with no duplicates

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a function  that takes an array of strings and returns a single string consisting of the individual characters of all the argument strings, in alphabetic order, with no repeats.

```js
var join = ["test"];
var splt = (("sxhdj").split(""))
var sort = splt.sort()
var jn = sort.join("")
join.push(jn)


function removeDuplicates(join) {
  let newArr = {};
  join.forEach(function(x) { //forEach will call a function once for 
    if (!newArr[x]) {
      newArr[x] = true;
    }
  });
  return Object.keys(newArr);
}
console.log(removeDuplicates(join));
```

I can not get the current code to work

Comment: You're putting `test` and `randomized string` as key not each character as key, your code will work if you split `join` before loop though it in `removeDuplicates` function

Answer (score 1):

Check out the comments for the explanation.

Links of interest:

- [MDN `Array.prototype.sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).
- [MDN `Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)

```js
var splt = ("sxhdjxxddff").split("")

// You need to use localeCompare to properly 
// sort alphabetically in javascript, because
// the sort function actually sorts by UTF-16 codes
// which isn't necessarily always alphabetical
var sort = splt.sort((a, b)=>a.localeCompare(b))

// This is an easy way to remove duplicates
// by converting to set which can't have dupes
// then converting back to array
sort = [...new Set(sort)]

var jn = sort.join("");
console.log(jn);
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this :) Hope it helps!

```js
const string = 'aabbccd';
const array = string.split('');
let sanitizedArray = [];
array.forEach(char => {
    // Simple conditional to check if the sanitized array already 
    // contains the character, and pushes the character if the conditional 
    // returns false

    !sanitizedArray.includes(char) && sanitizedArray.push(char)
})
let result = sanitizedArray.join('')


console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
const data = ['ahmed', 'ghoul', 'javscript'];
const result = [...data.join('')]
.filter((ele, i, arr) => arr.lastIndexOf(ele) === i)
.sort()
.join('');

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are probably better ways to do it, one way is to map it to an object, use the keys of the object for the used letters, and than sorting those keys.

```js
const words = ['foo', 'bar', 'funky'];
const sorted =
  Object.keys(
    ([...words.join('')])  // combine to an array of letters
      .reduce((obj, v) => obj[v] = 1 && obj, {}) // loop over and build hash of used letters
    ).sort()  //sort the keys

console.log(sorted.join(''))
```